# Weird warning with printf and integers

Tags: c, format, printf, escaping, uint32-t

I'm becoming crazy with the following code and the GCC compiler (v11.4 to x86_64 on Linux):

```
static void disasm_TESTSX_X(char *__buffer, test_inst_t *inst) {
    __buffer += sprintf(__buffer, "testsx %lx", ((uint32_t)(((int32_t)(TEST_TESTSX_X_x_i)))));
}

static void disasm_TESTW_X(char *__buffer, test_inst_t *inst) {
        __buffer += sprintf(__buffer, "testw %lx", (((uint32_t)(TEST_TESTW_X_x_i)) + 1L));

}
```

First form gives me a warning at compilation time (I should use %x) while the second does not. TEST_TESTW_X_x_i is of type uint8_t. Yet, both expressions are explicitly converted to uint32_t (code is not very readable as it is generated code).

Thanks to anyone that could help me.

Comment: The final `+ 1L` makes the type long.

Comment: That seems a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  Given `TEST_TESTW_X_x_i` having type `uint8_t` (why even that, instead of `unsigned int`?), I would just use `1u` instead of `1L` in the latter case to get an `unsigned int` *without any casts*, and use a single cast to `unsigned int` in the former case (or even add `0u` and avoid casting, given the parallelism).  Then both `sprintf` use `%x`.

Comment: @Hugues Cassé, Curious, `"%lX"` is for `unsigned long`, and code already has casts to types `uint32_t`, `int32_t`, and starts with `uint8_t`.  So far, all end up as some _unsigned_.  Why introduce a _signed_ type of `long` with `+ 1L`?

Answer (score 3):

> `"testsx %lx"` … I should use %x…

Neither is correct for converting a `uint32_t` value. To convert a `uint32_t` to hexadecimal, change `"testsx %lx"` to `"testsx %" PRIx32` and insert `#include <inttypes.h>`.

`uint32_t` may be `unsigned` in some C implementations, `unsigned long` in others, and some other type in yet others. So neither `%x` nor `%lx` will be correct in every C implementation. `PRIx32`, defined in `<inttypes.h>`, will be replaced by a string literal with a correct conversion specifier for `uint32_t` in the C implementation being used.

> Yet, both expressions are explicitly converted to uint32_t…

No, they are not. The argument in the second case is `(((uint32_t)(TEST_TESTW_X_x_i)) + 1L)`, which is the sum of a `uint32_t` expression and `1L`. In a C implementation where `long` is wider than `uint32_t`, the left operand of `+` will be converted to `long`, and the type of the result will be `long`.

Answer (score 2):

> First form gives me a warning at compilation time (I should use %x) while the second does not. TEST_TESTW_X_x_i is of type uint8_t. Yet, both expressions are explicitly converted to uint32_t (code is not very readable as it is generated code).

Yes, both expansions of the macro are converted to type `uint32_t`, but only in the first case is that result being passed to `printf`.  In the second case, it is that `uint32_t` result ***plus `1L`***.  When the sum is evaluated, the operands are converted to a common type, and the result has that type.  It should not be too surprising, then, that different conversion specifiers are appropriate for the different cases.

In particular, in the event that your `uint32_t` is the same type as `unsigned int` (relatively common), correctly-matching `printf` conversion specifiers will not have any width specifier.  That is, you would use `%x` instead of `%lx`.  Technically, that applies even if `long unsigned int` is also 32 bits wide.

In that case, however, the type of integer constant `1L`, which is `long int`, has higher integer conversion rank than `uint32_t`. Therefore, when the addition is performed, the type chosen for the result will not be `uint32_t`. It will be `long int` if that type can represent all the values representable by `uint32_t`, or `unsigned long int` otherwise.  (This is an application of the "usual arithmetic conversions".)  The conversion specifier `%lx` is consistent with type `unsigned long int`.  It is not consistent with [`signed`] `long int`, but it is conceivable that the compiler would not warn about that mismatch.

Summary:

- your `uint32_t` is probably the same as `unsigned int`.  In this case, `%x` is a correct `printf` conversion specifier for `(uint32_t)(((int32_t)(TEST_TESTSX_X_x_i)))`, but `%lx` is not.
- Given `uint32_t` the same as `unsigned int`, the type of `((uint32_t)(TEST_TESTW_X_x_i)) + 1L)` is either `unsigned long int` (if that is also a 32-bit type) or otherwise `long int`.  `%lx` is a correct `printf` conversion specifier for `unsigned long int`, but `%x` is not.  *Neither* is correct for `long int`, but you might nevertheless not get an warning about `%lx` in that case.

---

Additionally, when you are doing formatted I/O involving the explicit-width integer types, it is to your advantage to use the provided macros for expressing the appropriate conversion specifiers.  For example:

```
sprintf(__buffer, "testsx %" PRIx32, (uint32_t)(TEST_TESTSX_X_x_i));
```

If you can't be sure about the type of the expression whose value you are trying to format, however, then it is wise to convert it to a known type.  In this case, that might be something like

```
sprintf(__buffer, "testw %" PRIx32, (uint32_t)((TEST_TESTW_X_x_i) + 1L));
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit of re-hash of existing answers, but plus a tip.

**Use matching specifiers and types with `*printf()`**

`"testsx %lx", ((uint32_t)(((int32_t)(TEST_TESTSX_X_x_i))))` attempts to print a `uint32_t` with an `unsigned long` specifier.  Those are not certainly the same.

**Avoid math in `*printf()` arguments that result in an ambigous type.**

`(((uint32_t)(TEST_TESTW_X_x_i)) + 1L` adds a `uint32_t` with a `long` creating a sum of either type `uint32_t` **or** `long`.

---

**Tip: Get the type circus done before printing.**

```
static void disasm_TESTW_X(char *__buffer, test_inst_t *inst) {
    unsigned long x = ((uint32_t)(TEST_TESTW_X_x_i)) + 1L;  // Better with + 1u
    __buffer += sprintf(__buffer, "testw %lx", x);
}
```

**BTW, `__buffer` is updated, yet results discarded.**

Perhaps due to problem simplification.  I'd expect:

```
static char *disasm_TESTW_X(char *__buffer, test_inst_t *inst) {
    unsigned long x = ((uint32_t)(TEST_TESTW_X_x_i)) + 1L;  // Better with + 1u
    __buffer += sprintf(__buffer, "testw %lx", x);
    return __buffer;
}
```